# Ubuntu to replace windows xp

Tags: boot, system

In need of replacing the very out dated XP sp2 on computer

downloaded the latest ISO file from down load centre -which was in a compressed file

i originally burnt onto a cd disc on basis I could then boot from CD and then have a seamless change over to Ubuntu

I don't appear to be able to boot from the disc as first option, I checked the boot sequence this was all confirmed despite hitting F12 to change boot location no luck period.

Should this ISO file be unzipped or decompressed and then boot from cd disc or am I missing something

alternative is I try and deinstall XP from computer altogether and hopefully then I can boot from disc ?

Comment: What exact iso did you download -- 32 or 64 bit?  Ubuntu needs a DVD, not a CDROM these days, so try Lubuntu (likehttp://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/bionic/release/lubuntu-18.04-alternate-i386.iso ).  Burning the iso to disk takes a tool like rufus, unetbootin, or Infra recorder. You shouldn't need to do anything to the disk to try out the CDROM.

Comment: It's definitely not necessary to uninstall Windows XP or anything. Also check https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop for a step-by-step instruction on how to install. :)

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! A few possible reasons: You burnt a wrong file (please post a link), you didn’t burn it bootable (post what you see when you view the disc on Windows), your PC’s architecture does not match the install medium (today’s Ubuntu is offered as 64-bit only while a machine running XP is likely to be 32-bit). Please [edit] your question to narrow the problem down.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to uninstall your Windows XP or extract the files from ISO.
When you burn ISO, burn it with your CD/DVD burning program (Burn image to disc).

Then make sure in BIOS is set the booting sequence: CD booting before the your hard disc.

You can verify the booting sequence with another CD/DVD (e.g. Windows installation disc).